# Line Numbering from .tex file lines

Tags: line-numbering

Is it possible to have a feature similar to the `lineno` package that outputs the .tex file line number that the pdf line came from?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lineno, blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \blindtext

    \begin{linenumbers}
        \blindtext % the lineno output numbers here show 8

        \blindtext % the lineno output numbers here show 10
    \end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

In other words, I do not want the paragraph to number the lines 1..N, just show 8 on the first numbered paragraph line (or all of the associated pdf output lines) and 10 for the following paragraph.

I realize this gets difficult with `\input` or `\include` entries also.  I believe this feature does not exist right now, but I am curious if it is even possible with `pdflatex`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Just out of curiosity, what do 8 and 10 represent in your case?

Comment: @karlkoeller: The line numbers of the lines in the source file.

Comment: @Heiko thanks, I didn't understand the question correctly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not entirely impossible, because there is `\inputlineno`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newenvironment{linenumbers}{%
  \everypar{\marginpar{\the\inputlineno}}%
}{}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext

    \begin{linenumbers}
        \blindtext % the lineno output numbers here show 8

        \blindtext % the lineno output numbers here show 10
    \end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

However LaTeX uses `\everypar` very often, thus many problems are to be expected.

Comment: I would like to see this feature added at some point.  My goal is to help me to quickly identify the line in the .tex file of where I need to edit.  For example, if I have a typo, I could see where to go very quickly.  Do you have a recommendation if this could be added in the LaTeX scripting (painfully?) or is this something that needs to be added into the internal engine?

Comment: @Tele: There are many TeX IDEs/viewers that provide "inverse search" (e.g. source code specials with DVI or [syncTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118489/what-exactly-is-synctex) with PDF).