# Instant Preview of Latex to PDF in silent mode with fast compiling

Tags: pdftex, compiling, preview

Please i am working on a project should provide fast compiling of Latex files in silent mode so the user should not see any process and just preview the final pdf file produced and i need it faster than usual i tried to use pdflatex by hidden command line but it was slow which takes 4-5 seconds to preview pdf then i tried to use TeXWorks it was really fast but i can not hide it so any suggestion guys.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: How come TeXWorks is faster than pdflatex? I assume TeXWorks is just a front-end that *calls* pdflatex...

Comment: TeXworks has an "integrated pdf viewer", so to compare you should use `pdflatex` coupled to a viewer that automatically updates, e.g. via synctex.

Comment: Welcome @OSjerick if you have any idea about that i will be grateful

Comment: @AndrewSwann please tell me what is the synctex

Comment: @lhf i did not say that in the two cases i use pdflatex one time from cmd and the other from TeXWorks the TeXWorks Compile it faster than cmd

Comment: See this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118489/15925 about synctex

Comment: @AndrewSwann thank you for your fast response

Comment: Have you considered using `\includeonly`?

Answer (score 2):

This problem was tackled successfully on NeXTstep where the TeX process would allow access to a .dvi file after a complete page was written to it via IPC (InterProcess Communication).

This feature seems to now be part of pytex and the TeX Daemon --- one can improve TeX performance by:

- not loading unnecessary packages
- selectively processing only a portion of a document using `\includeonly` if it is large enough to be broken up into included files
- building your macros efficiently (use font instances if using fontspec is one common source of needless re-processing)
- only accessing graphics once (save them to a box and re-use them as needed)
- building a format which pre-loads all of your packages (this was much easier on Textures which had a specific menu feature for it) --- ISTR David Carlisle putting a tool for that up on CTAN.

And:

- keeping the TeX process in memory and leaving it running as a Daemon -- see pytex http://www.pytex.org/ (note AIUI that this is difficult on Windows since it blocks reading a file from stdin if it's still being written to)

Everything else is pretty straight-forward, but it's that last which would be the big pay-off --- I've been disappointed that TeX's IPC hasn't been seen as needful since modern machines have become so fast.