# Synctex in Texmaker and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, texmaker

I am using Texmaker 4.3 and LuaLaTeX. I have set the `"-synctex=1"` option to the `pdflatex` command. But the built-in pdf viewer will not jump directly to the position in the PDF file that corresponds to the current line in the (La)TeX source file.

Also, with a right-click on a word in the built-in pdf viewer (context menu), the editor will not jump to the corresponding line in the source file.

The setting I have is:

```
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I am wondering if I have done something wrong with the setup? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your writeup is a bit confusing: The title and the first sentence mention LuaLaTeX, but the rest of the piece appears to be about pdfLaTeX. Please indicate which format you're interested in. Separately, please indicate which version of TeXLive you use.

Comment: `"/usr/texbin/lualatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

Comment: If there are spaces in the path to the working directory, SyncTex does not work.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118489/what-exactly-is-synctex) for you can see more information about `synctex`.