# Extra files when compiling tex

Tags: compiling

When building a LaTeX file (with Texstudio, if that's important) in addition to the `.tex` and `.pdf` files, there are also `.aux`, `.log`, and `.synctex.gz` created.  What do these extra files *do*?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7770/file-extensions-of-latex-related-files might be what you are after. See also the related links, _e.g._ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files

Comment: .aux holds information like cross referencing. If you compile and then later delete this file, you'll need to recompile multiple times (again!), it also has listed the packages and document class you used, etc... .log is the log file. See also [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11123/4778) and [What exactly is SyncTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118489/4778)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.log`file is the compilation report. It mentions any errors  or warnings from the compiler.  It's very useful in case of problems.

The `.aux` file stores information for the compiler such as cross references and other elements, to build the table of contents, bibliographic references, indexes, &c.

`synctex.gz` is a (compressed) synchronisation file, which allows to go with one clic from a point in the source-code to the corresponding point in the .pdf, and back.