# Thumbnails Instead of Page numbers in TeXmaker's built-in PDF Viewer (separate window)

Tags: texmaker, viewers

I wonder if there is a setting or workaround for seeing thumbnails instead of page numbers in TeXmaker's built-in pdf reader. I used to use TeXstudio, which is a fork of TeXmaker, and it has such a feature yet it also has some issues with eps files in Mac OS.

And I am not sure if using an external pdf viewer would give me the option for switching between text and code.

Thanks already!

Comment: How is the second question related to the first? I think I am missing something here ;) but maybe you can help me.

Comment: This is perhaps more of a question about a pdf browser than one about tex....

Comment: You might be looking for SyncTeX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118489/15676 which I believe most of the IDE style editors use.