# SHareLatex PDF Viewer/DVI Viewer

Tags: sharelatex

we are creating a Latex Online Editor Compiler, The compiler Part and the Viewer part etc are over, but one problem i can't able to solve, In sharelatex, if we click the Pdf Viewer inside some Text, it will redirect the cursor to the Textbox containing Tex document, Can anyone help me in educating the logic behind that functionality in Sharelatex

[image]

Comment: I guess they use `synctex`, see e.g. [What exactly is SyncTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118489), though exactly how it is implemented I have no idea. You could look at their code though: https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for your timely help, your post gave me an idea of what is behind that Viewer :-)

Comment: It looks that you are using the browser PDF viewer. I think it will be a challenge to change the browser viewer to respond to clicks and get the synctex information from the server (?). I wouldn't know where to start but good luck with it. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: @alfC Yes true and ideally i changed the Pdf Acrobat viewer to Pdf.js and now trying out with pdfsync to sync pdf and latex source