# Can SyncTeX corrupt the .pdf file layout?

Tags: forward-inverse-search

I know that the `-src-specials` option can corrupt the `.pdf` file when I compile(d) a `.tex` file with the `\pdfoutput=1` option (I know it's not recommended to use `\pdfoutput=1`). E.g.

```bash
latex -src-specials file.tex
```

where the `.tex` file contains the string `\pdfoutput=1`.

Does the `-synctex=1` option do the same? Can I use it safely?

I mean: using

```bash
latex -synctex=1 file.tex
```

where, again, the `.tex` file contains the string `\pdfoutput=1`.

**Note.** I'm forced to use `\pdfoutput=1`. It's not my choice.

Comment: '\pdfoutput' was, as far as I remember, a switch to tell pdflatex to produce a pdf and not a dvi. The function of synctex is very different: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118491/4736 Does compiling a file with 'latex ...' work despite the use of '\pdfoutput=1'? However, are you compiling 20 year old texfiles?

Comment: I use synctex to enable reverse-search in the pdf-file. I'm not compiling old texfiles.