# synctex not working when path has letters with accents

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, forward-inverse-search

I tried many times and found that when my path to my latex files contains an 'é', or any other similar letter with an accent, my pdf to tex editor link doesn't work (Ctrl+space and Ctrl+click).
I'm using TexMaker and PDFLatex on Windows.

Does anybody have a solution for me ? It's a path I cannot rename.

Comment: Creating a Directory Junction (with mklink /j ) does work (mklink /d doesn't), thanks for it. But if anybody has another solution so that I don't have to make a link whenever I encounter this issue, I would take it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Answer:** Create a [virtual/symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) that only contains allowed characters (Windows: `mklink` or Linux: `ln`).
- **PS:** For information about SyncTeX in general, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118489).